# Split screen and scrolling with one side frozen

Tags: android

I have searched the posts here for a specific answer to this question, and although there are many responses to split screen problems, I have found none that relate to what I want to do.  I am not a developer, but I have one who is working for me.  He is having difficulty finding a solution to this problem.

I am working on an Android app that requires a vertical split screen. The left side of the screen scrolls up and down only, and basically has product names.  The right side of the screen contains columns of data for the products.  This data is much too wide to display on one screen.  I need the data and columns in the right screen to scroll in all directions, while the product names only scroll in the vertical.  Now, both the names, and the data need to remain locked together so that when one is scrolled vertically the other follows.

I sure hope someone can point me in the right direction, or tell me it’s not possible, because my programmer seems to be going nuts.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I tagged it as Android and I thought that was all I needed to do.  But yes, it is for an Android app.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the app is targeted for tablets, because split screen would not look good on a regular phone screen. Take a look at the [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

Comment: This has been resolved for me now.  The function works great for my app.